# repay the loan I gave my LLC

Tags: loans, limited-liability-company

I gave money to my LLC (in the US) and now that the business has made some money, I want to pay myself back.  If the LLC writes the check in 2020, can it still be deducted from the 2019 business tax return (1065 form)?

Comment: Nope. That would be a 2020 expense.

Comment: Plus, 1) payment of a "loan" wouldn't be an expense at all (at least not the interest portion), and 2) if it _were_, it would be an expense to the business (assuming a pass-through) and income to you, so the taxes would offset.

Comment: @DStanley I think you mean interest on a loan *would* be an expense, and principal repayment *wouldn't*?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes that's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: Does 'my' mean a single owner? If so, you shouldn't be using 1065 at all -- either no return if disregarded or 1120-S if you elected S-corp.

Answer (score 3):

When you made the loan to your LLC, you shouldn't have included it as a personal expense, and you shouldn't have included it as LLC income. By the same token, when you repay that loan, it isn't an expense to the LLC, or income to you personally.

I suggest you get a professional accountant's advice (and not a $20 / hour bookkeeper you saw on a flyer taped to a lamppost, either), because it seems you are in a bit over your head with how your financial situation has been set up.